# Controlling SMS notifications

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have created a broadcast receiver that uses the SMS_RECEIVER. So far everything works fine with it. Now I would like to modify the notification settings for the sms e.g. adjust volume, turn on vibrate, change audio file...

Basically, I would like this app to duplicate the custom ringtone notification. So I would get the sms, check the senders phone number, and change the notification accordingly. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this per text message. Could someone please link me to some documentation or a code snipet of how to do this?

*(I found an example on how to silence the phone but the problem with that example is the phone will remain silenced until the code/user turns the volume back on. I would like to only perform the action on the text message being received at the time, this way it will not affect other functionality of the phone)*